# image windows phone database

Tags: database, windows-phone-7

hi i devolop a Windows phone application with local database 
this is a table from my database

```
[Table]
    public class DBannotation 
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, CanBeNull = false )]
        public string annotguid { get; set; }
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, CanBeNull = false)]
        public int foruserid { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public int annversion { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string chapath { get; set; }
```

}

i must  insert an image into database but i didn't find how i can do that what type of column i must add 
thanks in advance for your helpthanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should store the images in the Isolated Storage, and to avoid conflict of naming the images, you should use GUID to name the images. And of course in your table, you save that GUID.

```
public static string SaveImage(Stream imageStream, int orientation, int quality)
{
    var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    using (var isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (isolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
            isolatedStorage.DeleteFile(fileName);

        IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = isolatedStorage.CreateFile(fileName);
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(imageStream);

        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
        wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, orientation, quality);
        fileStream.Close();
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

Comment: this is my second solution but my constraint is the number of image

Comment: You can always check the Quota of the Isolated Storage, and give some feedback to the users for how much spaced used/free. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstorage.quota.aspx

Answer (score -1):

in Table:
[Column]
  public byte[] Image { get; set; }

Xaml:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource BytesToImageConverter}}"....>



 public class BytesToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {

            byte[] bytes = value as byte[];
            if (bytes == null) return null;

            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            SetSource(bytes, image);
            return image;

        }

        private async static void SetSource(byte[] source, BitmapImage image)
        {
            var stream = await Utils.ToRandomAccessStream(source);
            await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried this solution but when i save in the database i have this exception  'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll Byte array truncation to a length of 8000